# React automatically importing all the CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

So I'm doing a React App, Where the css files remains on src/dist/css, where src is located in the same local of App.js, the thing is I just want to import one single CSS file, but when I'm going to see every css file were automatically imported somehow.

I want to prevent this, because it's conflicting with the normal css screen.

[These are the only things I'm Importing. ( IMAGE )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ewdL.png)

[But All of these are being imported, I don't know if is something with React or the Server.. ( IMAGE )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfIVY.png)

EDIT: I figured out its because of React Router, Who is importing all the CSS to the App.JS, Still don't know how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent this. Alternatives that you can look at are:

1. use BEM naming to have no conflicts all over the code.
2. use module.css, CSS module is a simple thing that can help you resolve the conflict without changing much of the CSS you have written.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you using styled-components or module.css. and tailwind also.